# Can you use neovim in a gui like mvim or gvim? (Mac OS X)

Tags: neovim, gvim, macvim, macos

Maybe a stupid question but is it possible to run neovim on a GUI like gvim or mvim?

I need some GUI to do remote work within Filezilla

Thanks

Comment: Yes. There's, for instance, [neovim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/blob/master/README.md). Why would you need a GUI to do remote work? (If anything, I find it much easier to do remote work on Vim on a terminal, through SSH. With a GUI, the latency is typically higher.) Also, please edit the question to indicate which platform you're on (Mac OS X?), that typically restricts answers on what options are available.

Comment: Okay thanks, I struggle a bit to install the GUI. Do you know of any guide? Do i have to build it from scoure?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/qvacua/vimr

Comment: On Mac OS, use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Google and you'll find instructions or a port of neovim-qt for Homebrew...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several GUIs for Neovim because it externalises the user interface elements, so any GUI can draw these in different ways. There's [a list](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Related-projects#gui) that tracks the status of these projects. My favourites are [FVim](https://github.com/yatli/fvim) and [goneovim](https://github.com/akiyosi/goneovim) and both support remote sessions

Answer (score 4):

I recommend neovim-qt ([GitHub - equalsraf/neovim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt)).  It is plain vanilla, cross-platform, stable, actively developed, and fast enough.

To install on Mac using Homebrew:

```
brew tap equalsraf/homebrew-neovim-qt
brew install neovim-qt
```

To install on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install neovim-qt
```

Neovim-qt is included in Window's port of Neovim (by running `nvim-qt.exe`)

Another recommended GUI is Neovide ([GitHub - Kethku/neovide](https://github.com/Kethku/neovide)),   It has more feature and more graphic effects than neovim-qt and it is probably the most popular GUI version of Neovim as of 7/2021.

There are also few others, but I prefer GUI apps to be cross-platform and also not to be based on Electron, which typically (but not always) run slower.